# How to save a file stored in SQL Database to a file on the server

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, filestream, sqlfilestream

I have a situation where I am trying to retrieve a PDF file that has been saved as a binary file on the database. I can get the file and send it back through the browser to allow the client to download or open the PDF, but what I need to do is get the file and write it back to the file system on the server.

Can anyone point me to an article, or maybe the methods I would need to use to do something like this?

I have tried various code elements around filestreams and such.

Comment: This may help : [link](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Save-and-Retrieve-Files-from-SQL-Server-Database-using-ASPNet.aspx) focus on 
"Retrieving the File from Database"

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Thanks Marc, I did add a tag, I am working with SQL Server, the Microsoft product.

Malav, I found that link and tried what it was suggesting, there were a few problems with the code on that page, and the code created a download to the client computer, unless I am overlooking something here.